# SQL Server : how to convert distinct item in row to column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am setting up a T-SQL query which will convert rows to column however gets stuck in creating this. Have created below T-SQL statements, and using this and i need to convert row to column

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME,
    CAST(ROUND(AVG(duration) / 1000000.0, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS AVGDuration,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), timestamp, 105), 
    database_name
FROM 
    [DBA].[dbo].[longrun]
GROUP BY 
    OBJECT_NAME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), timestamp, 105), database_name
ORDER BY 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), timestamp, 105)
```

Current output:

```
OBJECT_NAME         AVGDuration     Date          database
------------------------------------------------------------
XYZ                 112.35          May 14 2019   X
sp_executesql       60.01           May 14 2019   Y
XYZ                 132.35          May 15 2019   X
sp_executesql       80.01           May 15 2019   Y
```

Dates should be converted to column and Datetime is dynamic value and it should not be hard coded

Expected output:

```
Object Name     Database  May 14 2019   May 15 2019  
------------------------------------------------------------
XYZ             X         112.35        132.35
sp_executesql   Y          60.01         80.01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PIVOT to get your desired output-

```
WITH CTE(OBJECT_NAME,AVGDuration,Date,[database])
AS
(
    SELECT OBJECT_NAME,
    CAST(round(avg(duration)/1000000.0,2) as numeric(36,2)) as AVGDuration,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), timestamp, 105) Date,
    database_name
    FROM [DBA].[dbo].[longrun]
    GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), timestamp, 105),database_name
    ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), timestamp, 105)
)

SELECT OBJECT_NAME,[database],[May 14 2019],[May 15 2019]
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM CTE
)A
PIVOT(
    MAX(AVGDuration)
    FOR Date IN([May 14 2019],[May 15 2019])
)PVT
```

In case of Dynamic Date list, you can try this-

```
DECLARE @ColumnList VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sqlCommand VARCHAR(MAX)


;WITH CTE(Date)
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), timestamp, 105) Date
    FROM [DBA].[dbo].[longrun]
)

SELECT  @ColumnList = STUFF((SELECT  ('],[' +  A.Date)
        FROM CTE A
        ORDER BY CAST(A.Date AS DATE) 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1,1,'')+']'
FROM CTE


SET @sqlCommand= 
N'SELECT OBJECT_NAME,[database],'+SUBSTRING(@ColumnList,2,LEN(@ColumnList))+'
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM 
    (
        SELECT OBJECT_NAME,
        CAST(round(avg(duration)/1000000.0,2) as numeric(36,2)) as AVGDuration,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), timestamp, 105) Date,
        database_name
        FROM [DBA].[dbo].[longrun]
        GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), timestamp, 105),database_name
        ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), timestamp, 105)
    )
    CTE
)A
PIVOT(
    MAX(AVGDuration)
    FOR Date IN('+SUBSTRING(@ColumnList,2,LEN(@ColumnList))+')
)PVT'


--PRINT @sqlCommand
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

Comment: fantastic it worked ,one more help required in this how should i print column in date wise like 1st may,2nd may,3rd may, currently its giving output randomly like first column 2nd may then 1st may and like that and need to add case if its NULL the print "No execution on day"

Comment: Not sure why, but here with my test data, Dates are always selecting as Ascending order even if I change the order inconsistently. Puzzled :(

Comment: No worries thanks, I will put those data in another table and select as per requirement ,thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193918/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-sanky).